# Registering is not adding the new user to the database [php]

Tags: php, mysql, database

So im new to php and im trying to create an admin panel for my webpage, one of the things i tried to do was to create a register system. For some reason it fails to add the users to the database.

My db.php file -

```
<?php $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'admin_panel'); ?>
```

and my register.php file -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Register - Admin panel</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
include 'db.php'; 
   ?>
  <?php 
  include 'functions.php';
  ?>
<?php
include 'title_bar.php';
?>
<h3>Register Here: </h3>
<form method='post'>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $password = $_POST['password']; 
 
 if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
  echo "<p>Fields should not be empty</p>";
 } else{ 
 $password = md5($_POST['password']);
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,user_level,type) 
VALUES ('','$username','$password','2','1')");
echo "Registration was succesful";
 }
}
?>﻿
User name: 
<input type ='text' name = 'username' />
<br/><br/>
Password:
<input type = 'password' name = 'password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value='register' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the problem? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to put your php code outside of `form tag`

Comment: Thank you! I did it, but still MySQL returned an empty result :(

Comment: @Saty What difference will that make?

Comment: Doesn't really matter whether it's inside of the form tag or not @Saty the php will be executed before the form is.

Comment: @RalfsR What do you see? Do you get `Registration is succesful` output, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it's registration is succesful output

Comment: Add a check to see if the query was executed without error.

Comment: Okay, next, try seeing what [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) gives you, and / or output the SQL string and post that.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that you're open to SQL injections attacks. You're already using mysqli, so look up how to use prepared statements.

Comment: @JonStirling should i add mysqli_error like that?  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,user_level,type) 
VALUES ('','$username','$password','2','1')"or die mysqli_error($con));

Comment: alright mysqli_error returned ''Unknown column 'type' in 'field list' "

Comment: Right, so there's your answer :).

Comment: So i fixed the last error, but now i got a new error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users VALUES (' ' , '$username' , '$password' , '2' , '1')") or die (mysqli_error($con)); and i cant seem to fix this one

Comment: Why did you remove the column list?

Comment: Please provide the table's CREATE TABLE definition.

Comment: You mean like this ? http://puu.sh/oIcfO/09dd8a15f1.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate php variable within " ", so try this..
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,user_level,type) 
VALUES (' ', ' ".$username." ',' ".$password." ','2','1')");

Comment: No it won't. Please read what's already been said, and also look up how strings and variable interpolation works in PHP.

Comment: there is no type column in your table right ?? if so , remove type from query and corresponding value. Also change the username and password type to varchar or char.

Answer (score 0):

You should either specify the ID or do not put it into insert at all if you have it as primary auto-increment.
Check http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php for last SQL error

Answer (score -1):

You haven't defined action of the form

```
<form method='post' action="<?php echo $_SEVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

This will submit form to the same page and you can access username and password.

Comment: If a form action is not defined, the default behavior is to submit to itself.